Flutter BLE cannot detect Raspberry Pi 4 Bluetooth
I am trying to connect to my Raspberry Pi 4 bluetooth from a Flutter app.
However, the flutter app is not even recognizing the Raspberry Pi 4 bluetooth.
This is the app screen which only shows the earphone.
App Interface showing the available bluetooth devices
This is my phone's bluetooth control screen which shows both the Pi - nil and my local PC.
New Pair Screen
Ans this is my code -
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    
    class ConnectDeviceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _BluetoothModuleState createState() => _BluetoothModuleState();
    }
    
    class _BluetoothModuleState extends State<ConnectDeviceScreen> {
      final FlutterReactiveBle _ble = FlutterReactiveBle();
      List<DiscoveredDevice> _devices = [];
      StreamSubscription<DiscoveredDevice>? _scanSubscription;
      StreamSubscription<ConnectionStateUpdate>? _connectionSubscription;
      bool _isScanning = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _checkBleStatus();
      }
    
      void _checkBleStatus() {
        _ble.statusStream.listen((status) {
          print('BLE status: $status');
          if (status == BleStatus.ready) {
            _startScan();
          }
        });
      }
    
      void _startScan() {
        setState(() {
          _isScanning = true;
          _devices.clear();
        });
    
        _scanSubscription = _ble.scanForDevices(
          withServices: [], // Empty list means scan for all devices
          scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency,
        ).listen(
          (device) {
            setState(() {
              final knownDeviceIndex =
                  _devices.indexWhere((d) => d.id == device.id);
              if (knownDeviceIndex >= 0) {
                _devices[knownDeviceIndex] = device;
              } else {
                _devices.add(device);
              }
            });
          },
          onError: (Object error) {
            print('Scanning failed: $error');
            setState(() {
              _isScanning = false;
            });
          },
        );
    
        // Stop scanning after 10 seconds
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 60), () {
          _stopScan();
        });
      }
    
      void _stopScan() {
        _scanSubscription?.cancel();
        setState(() {
          _isScanning = false;
        });
      }
    
      Future<void> _connectToDevice(DiscoveredDevice device) async {
        try {
          print('Connecting to ${device.name}...');
          _connectionSubscription = _ble
              .connectToDevice(
            id: device.id,
            connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
          )
              .listen(
            (connectionState) {
              print('Connection state: ${connectionState.connectionState}');
              if (connectionState.connectionState ==
                  DeviceConnectionState.connected) {
                print('Connected to ${device.name}');
                // Here you can perform operations like service discovery,
                // reading/writing characteristics, etc.
                // For example:
                // _discoverServices(device.id);
              }
            },
            onError: (Object error) {
              print('Connection failed: $error');
            },
          );
        } catch (e) {
          print('Failed to connect: $e');
        }
      }
    
      // Example of reading a characteristic
      // You'll need to replace the UUIDs with your specific ones
      Future<void> _readCharacteristic(String deviceId) async {
        final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
          serviceId: Uuid.parse("YOUR_SERVICE_UUID"),
          characteristicId: Uuid.parse("YOUR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID"),
          deviceId: deviceId,
        );
        try {
          final response = await _ble.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
          print('Read characteristic: ${response}');
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error reading characteristic: $e');
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Bluetooth Devices')),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _devices.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(_devices[index].name),
                subtitle: Text(_devices[index].id),
                trailing: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Connect'),
                  onPressed: () => _connectToDevice(_devices[index]),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _isScanning ? _stopScan : _startScan,
            child: Icon(_isScanning ? Icons.stop : Icons.search),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _scanSubscription?.cancel();
        _connectionSubscription?.cancel();
        super.dispose();
      }
    }

Why can't the flutter app recognize the Raspberry Pi ? When I am connecting normally, using the default phone pairing method outside the flutter app, it connects fine with Pi.

Your phone's Bluetooth settings probably finds the Pi over Bluetooth classic. Are you running any software on the Pi that actually initiates BLE advertising? It doesn't advertise unless you tell it to.

@Emil I went to bluetoothctl on pi and turned discoverable on. Would that not do the work ? Or like I have a python script which listens for a connection and then connects to it. Should I have to invoke the function then ?

@Emil So my python script just binds a socket to a bluetooth port and listens to it. For it to work, the Pi needs to be paired and connected with a bluetooth device.
